# Populating Multiple Columns Simultaneously

Tags: sql, postgresql

Forewarning, I am new to SQL. Sorry in advance if this question doesn't make sense or my concept of what I'm trying to do is just completely off.

That aside, I'm trying to add in multiple columns from varying tables into a set of columns in a centralized table, and ideally I'd do this simultaneously. Am I on the right track thinking this should be accomplished through joins? Maybe unions?

I'd appreciate it if someone could show me an example or point me in the right direction. Thank you!

Edit for clarification:  I've got 3 tables. The old one, a new one, and a mapping table connecting the two,. I need to know how to populate the new table's columns simultaneously with the old table's values, via the mapping table.

Comment: So you have multiple input tables with the same number of rows and the rows are 1:1 to each other? Like different information about the same logical thing (e.g. a customer)?

Comment: Correct.  I've got 3 tables. The old one, a new one, and a mapping table connecting the two,. I need to know how to populate the new table's columns simultaneously with the old table's values, via the mapping table.

Comment: Join the three tables.

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe you should look more into Primary and Foreign Keys, and i suppose your table could have as foreign keys the other table primary keys, so this table would represent a relation from multiple tables.